# VBA; Invalid procedure or argument error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

A little background; 
I have to run a weekly reports for my job on Monday for the previous week, however I need to consolidated the material, I did and made a pivot table and I have to do this for multiple worksheets.  However I decided to create a macro to do this redundant task.  Created it now I seem get this error message "Invalid Procedure or Argument". I can't get it to open in my in a new work sheet, t his is my code  >>

```
Sub weekmaster()
'
' weekmaster Macro
' Macro for the week
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "weekmaster!R1C1:R1048576C62", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet9!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
    Sheets("Sheet9").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Order ID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```

Comment: You could get that error if the TableDestination is invalid. (i.e. a sheet with that name doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get an error if you run the macro more than once, or if `Sheet9` already exists (because the macro tries to create the same pivot table with the same name on the same sheet). If I am to assume that you  a **new** PivotTable in a **new** worksheet to be generated every time you go to your data sheet and run the macro, you can update your code with the following:

```
Dim myRange as Range
dim myNewSheet as Worksheet

' Stores all continuous data on the sheet in the myRange variable
Set myRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

' Adds a new sheet and stores it in the myNewSheet variable
Set myNewSheet = Sheets.Add

' Use the variables to create the new pivot table
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    myRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=myNewSheet.Cells(3, 1), DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion12

' Select your Order ID field
With myNewSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Order ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing one argument.  CreatePivotTable takes the following arguments:

expression.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination, TableName, ReadData, DefaultVersion)

1. TableDestination Required Variant The cell in the upper-left corner of the PivotTable report’s destination range (the range on the worksheet where the resulting PivotTable report will be placed). The destination range must be on a worksheet in the workbook that contains the PivotCache object specified by expression.
2. TableName Optional Variant The name of the new PivotTable report.
3. ReadData Optional Variant True to create a PivotTable cache that contains all of the records from the external database; this cache can be very large. False to enable setting some of the fields as server-based page fields before the data is actually read.
4. DefaultVersion Optional Variant The default version of the PivotTable report.

Subsequently, you'll probably want to add 'true' between your TableName and DefaultVersion.

Cheers, LC